# When to optimize renders in react with useMemo and useCallback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've read a few articles on when to optimize rendering in React, however, I still have some doubts.

```
const RepairNoticeContainer = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const history = useHistory();
    const { siteType, siteId } = useParams();

    const data = useSelector(pageSelectors.getData);

    const showRepairNotice = data.grid.cols.lg !== 36;

    const handleRepairClick = () => {
        dispatch(
            pagesActions.copyAndRepairCurrentPage(newPageId => {
                history.push(`/editor/${siteType}/${siteId}/pages/${newPageId}`);
            })
        );
    };

    return showRepairNotice ? <RepairNotice onRepairClick={handleRepairClick} /> : null;
};
```

As far as I can understand, it would be beneficial to use `useCallback`for `handleRepairClick` to avoid rerenders of `<RepairNotice/>`. But what about `showRepairNotice`variable? Should it be wrapped in a `useMemo` for optimization?

```
const RepairNotice = ({ onRepairClick }) => {
    const translate = useTranslator();

    let message = translate("repair_warning");
    message = message.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + message.slice(1);

    return (
        <MessageBox type="warning" icon="information11" className="mb-0 mt-2">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    <b>{translate("warning")}:</b> {message}
                </div>
                <div className="col-auto text-right">
                    <Button color="danger" onClick={onRepairClick} size="small">
                        {translate("repair_now")}
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </MessageBox>
    );
```

A simillar question for this example. Would it be beneficial to wrap `message` inside of `useMemo`?

```
const Page = ({ status }) => {
    const unsavedData = status?.unsavedData ? true : false;

    return (
        <Fade>
            <div className="Page">
                <NavConfirmModal active={unsavedData} onSavePage={onSavePage} />
            </div>
        </Fade>
    );
};
```

Lastly, should `useMemo` be used `unsavedData`?

Explanations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I can understand, it would be beneficial to use useCallback for handleRepairClick to avoid rerenders of

That's right. while wrapping `handleRepairClick` you will, simply speak, prevent creating a new instance of this function so it will save `RepairNotice` nested component from redundant rerenders because it relies on this function in props. Another good case for `useMemo` is when you're rendering a list of items and each relies on the same handler function declared in their parent.
[Very good `useCallback` explanation here.](https://dmitripavlutin.com/dont-overuse-react-usecallback/)

> But what about showRepairNotice variable? Should it be wrapped in a
> useMemo for optimization?

It's just a simple "equation" check which is really cheap from performance side - so there is really no need in `useMemo` here.

> Would it be beneficial to wrap message inside of useMemo?

Yes, it would. Since there are at least 3 actions javascript has to fire upon the `message` (`charAt`, `toLowerCase`, `slice`) and you don't really want this calculations to fire every time the `RepairNotice` component gets rerendered.

> should useMemo be used unsavedData?

It might be preferable to wrap unsavedData into `useMemo` if `NavConfirmModal` will be wrapped in [React.Memo](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_memo.asp) or in the case of "heavy calculations". So for the current case - it would not really make a difference. *(btw calculating `unsavedData` could be written just like `!!status?.unsavedData` to get boolean)*.

[And very good `useMemo` explanation here.](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-usememo-hook/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In case of `useMemo` I understand its uses for heavy computation stuff, but in terms of simple variables, like the `unsavedData`, should we, as a rule of thumb, always wrap them inside of `useMemo` if they are passed as props?

Comment: Ii would say "no" - it's not a rule of thumb, because it also depends on number of props/state that might change and also type of the dependencies (it's more complicated with `objects/arrays` since they are passed by reference in Javascript, not by value (like primitive types do). And lots of people would not really optimize such places before they really see a need in this.
Plus all this is closely connected with `React.memo` which is not a topic of a question directly, but here's a stackblitz example that might help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ubbuhc